# Create 3rd level foreach and loop the arrays and save it to data?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, module, opencart

I am using opencart 1.5.6.4 . I've create a module.

```
<?php $module_row = 1; ?>
<?php foreach ($modules as $module) { ?>

<?php $element = 1; ?>
<?php if(isset($module['tabs'])) { foreach($module['tabs'] as $tab) { ?>

<?php $elements = 1; ?>
<?php if(isset($tab['styles'])) { foreach($tab['styles'] as $style) {  ?>

<?php $elements++; } }  ?>

<?php $element++; }  } ?>

<?php $module_row++; } ?>
```

But 3rd level not working and saved.

```
<?php $elements = 1; ?>
    <?php if(isset($tab['styles'])) { foreach($tab['styles'] as $style) {  ?>
```

When i changed it to

```
<?php $elements = 1; ?>
        <?php foreach($tab as $style) { if ($style > 0) {  ?>
```

Not working properly.

What is the correct solution?

Comment: Why on earth do you open and close PHP on each line? It is quite confusing to read, especially the closing blocks.

Comment: You have mixed matched brackets `{`/`}`. You have 4 opening `{`, but 6 closing `}`. It looks like you need 1 after `if(isset($tab['styles']))`, and remove the 2nd one after `$module_row++;`

Comment: I do if(isset($tab['styles'])) {         and         <?php $module_row++; } ?> but not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add 3rd level foreach loop and save it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822458/how-to-add-3rd-level-foreach-loop-and-save-it)

Comment: Not working. Solution?

Answer (score 0):

You really need to go back and learn basics.  Use proper indentation, check value of arrays and variables, etc.

It's actually very difficult to understand your question and the two lines of code you give at the end don't even use the same variable names.  For anyone to make a reasonable attempt to help you, they would need to see the part of the code that's *not* working, in context.

All that being said, here's one way you could format what you posted above which I'd advise you to carefully study and consider if you have any intention of continuing in your efforts to write php:

```
<?php

$module_row = 1; 
foreach ($modules as $module) { 
    $element = 1;
    if (isset($module['tabs'])) {
        foreach($module['tabs'] as $tab) { 
            $elements = 1; 
            if (isset($tab['styles'])) {
                foreach($tab['styles'] as $style) {  
                    $elements++;
                }
            }  
            $element++;
        }
    } 
$module_row++;

?>
```

Comment: I talking about opencart compatibility and for module...  Not full of php.